# Verify file is successfully downloaded using assertion

Tags: jmeter

File is getting download in jmeter bin folder from 'Save Responses to a file' assertion.

I'm not able to verify the downloaded file, Is there any assertion available other than MD5Hex Assertion or I need to write JAVA/Groovy code?

Answer (score 2):

If you need to check file presence you can add a [JSR223 Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Assertion) and use the following code assuming [File.exists()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#exists--) function :

```
if (!new File('Bulk.pdf').exists()) {
    AssertionResult.setFailure(true)
    AssertionResult.setFailureMessage('File is absent') 
}
```

If the file will not be present you will get an error message like:

[image]

More information: [Scripting JMeter Assertions in Groovy - A Tutorial](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/scripting-jmeter-assertions-in-groovy-a-tutorial/)

Answer (score 0):

You can check using [notExists](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#notExists(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.LinkOption...)) with more readable version

```
import java.nio.file.*;
if (Files.notExists(Paths.get("Bulk.pdf"))) {
```